# How to classify data and deal with it as needed?

Tags: plotting

I have a list of data describing the coordinates (x-, y-axes) of points in the plane. For the same axis x, there may be several points and if the number of coordinate is odd just neglect the first or the last one. I want to know the average difference for the same coordinate x.
Part of the data is

```
data={{0.1, 1.21109}, {0.1, 1.16829}, {0.1, 1.21109}, {0.1, 1.16829}, {0.1,
   1.21109}, {0.1, 1.16829}, {0.1, 1.21109}, {0.1, 1.16829}, {0.1, 
  1.21109}, {0.1, 1.16829}, {0.1, 1.21109}, {0.1, 1.16829}, {0.1, 
  1.21109}, {0.1, 1.16829}, {0.1, 1.21109}, {0.1, 1.16829}, {0.15, 
  1.17271}, {0.15, 1.20571}, {0.15, 1.17271}, {0.15, 1.20571}, {0.15, 
  1.17271}, {0.15, 1.20571}, {0.15, 1.17271}, {0.15, 1.20571}, {0.15, 
  1.17271}, {0.15, 1.20571}, {0.15, 1.17271}, {0.15, 1.20571}, {0.15, 
  1.17271}, {0.15, 1.20571}, {0.15, 1.17271}, {0.15, 1.20571}, {0.15, 
  1.17271}, {0.15, 1.20571}, {0.15, 1.17271}, {0.15, 1.20571}, {0.15, 
  1.17271}, {0.15, 1.20571}, {0.15, 1.17271}, {0.15, 1.20571}, {0.2, 
  1.17552}, {0.2, 1.20246}, {0.2, 1.17552}, {0.2, 1.20246}, {0.2, 
  1.17552}, {0.2, 1.20246}, {0.2, 1.17552}, {0.2, 1.20246}, {0.2, 
  1.17552}, {0.2, 1.20246}};
```

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by average difference?

Comment: @That Gravity Guy For x=0.1, there are more than one pair of coordinates. The average difference is the mean value of the sum of the difference between every two points, i.e., `((data[[2, 2]] - data[[1, 2]]) + (data[[4, 2]] - data[[3, 2]]) + ...)/
 n`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:**

```
meandiffs = Values @ GroupBy[data, First, 
  Mean @ Thread[{#[[1, 1]], Subtract @@@ Partition[#[[All, 2]], 2]}]&];

GraphicsColumn[{ListPlot[data], ListLinePlot[meandiffs]}]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

```
means =  Values @ GroupBy[data,  First, Mean];

ListPlot[{data, means}, Joined -> {False, True}]
```

[image]

`means = Mean /@ GatherBy[data,  First]` gives the same result.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the mean value is good. But something like `((data[[2, 2]] - data[[1, 2]]) + (data[[4, 2]] - data[[3, 2]]))/2` is what I want.

Comment: @keanhy14, please see the update.

Comment: Really grateful for your job, that's what I need!

Comment: @keanhy14, you are most welcome.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
means = {#[[1, 1]], Mean[#[[All, 2]]]} & /@ GatherBy[data, First];
Show[
 {
  ListPlot[data],
  ListLinePlot[means]
 }
]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the distance between every two points is what I need.

Comment: But that is not what you wrote in your question. The "average difference for the same coordinate x" can also refer to the distance from the x-axis.

Comment: I'm sorry about that. Your suggestion also helps me a lot and I'm really grateful for it!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
avgdif[list_] := 2 (Total@list[[2 ;; ;; 2]] - Total@list[[;; ;; 2]]) / Length@list // Abs
{#[[1, 1]], avgdif@If[OddQ@Length@#, Most@#, #][[;; , 2]]} & /@ GatherBy[data, First]
```

> {{0.1, 0.0428}, {0.15, 0.033}, {0.2, 0.02694}}

Comment: That's nearly what I want. It will be better if `Abs` for the difference is added and the result is something like this `((data[[2, 2]] - data[[1, 2]]) + (data[[4, 2]] - data[[3, 2]]))/n`, where n is `2`, not `4`.